# Can not mount NAS Server on Windows 7 Machine

Tags: windows-7, networking, home-networking, nas

I have two NAS Servers in a network. Also I have two Windows 7 machines and one Windows XP machine. One of those Windows 7 machines is not able to mount the NAS servers! I can ping both servers successfully but I cannot access them. I am getting an error saying this path is not accessible with the errorcode 0x80070035.

I assume it has something to do with my Windows 7 installation but I don't want to reinstall until I haven't tried everything. Do you have an idea what I can do here? Let me know what additional informations you need to help me :-) Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was: A driver was missing. I was sure I had installed it before. It somehow got lost.

:-)

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the solution @sven. It helps the community.

Comment: You can't do it right after. you have to wait afaik two days to mark it solved